# ios container view of navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I guess I'm just stuck here on the logic of the design.  Big factor to consider...I'm trying to do everything programmatically.  In my AppDelegate, I'm assigning the tab bar controller as the root.  What I'm struggling with is how to display the login on top of the tab bar controller with it's own navigation bar and items.

First I tried making the LoginViewController as the root.  To navigate to the tab bar controller I used [self.navigationController setViewControllers] method.  That caused problems because I guess it was turning the login view into the tab bar view, so when trying to logout and going back to the root view, the login view was all messed up.

Now I'm trying to make the tab bar controller the root view and add a container view with my LoginViewController.  Problem with this is 1)The navigation bar from tab bar item 1 is still showing and 2)The tab bar itself is showing.  So I guess I'm asking a couple of things...how can I make the container view take up the entire screen with its own navigation controller...and what's the best way to implement a logout button to go back to the root view controller?

LogInView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIBarButtonItem *signup = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sign Up" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showSignUp:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = signup;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Log In" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 150, 100, 30);
[button setTitle:@"Login Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(push:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)push:(id)sender{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"something" forKey:@"something"];
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
}

- (void)showSignUp:(id)sender{
SignUpViewController *signup = [[SignUpViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signup animated:YES];
}
```

TabBarView1.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"something"] == nil) {
    LogInViewController *login = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:login];
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:login.view];
    [login didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
}
```

That much so far works...except for the part where I don't see LoginView's navigation bar with the buttons.  Second questionable method is logging out:

TabView4.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.title = @"Me";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logout:)];
}

- (void)logout:(id)sender{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"something"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
//that takes me back to the first tab and the login screen comes up...
//is that the best way to do this right now?
}
```

If anyone has any advice (and I know there are better ways to do this), please tell me.  But remember, I'm trying to make this work programmatically, without storyboards/segues/xibs.  Please help!

Correct Answer:  Modal on button press

```
- (void) modal:(id)sender{
LogInViewController *login = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *loginNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:login];
loginNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
loginNav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:loginNav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

That was just a try from the first tab on button click.  It comes up as full screen but without a nav bar...

Comment: You could always just present a navigationcontroller containing the login view controller modally full screen

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use a container view to do this. Just present (modally) the navigation controller (whose root view controller is the login view controller) from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab (with no animation, so it will be the first thing the user sees).

Comment: I just stumbled upon customizing the modal view.  Can one of you please give me an example of how to modally display a full navigation view controller?  I'll add the code that I just tried...can you please correct me?

Comment: I got it...I needed to add the UINavigationController after initializing LogInViewController.  Now it works!  All that writing and struggling and explaining my problems and such an easy solution.  I used modals in storyboard segues...but for some reason I didn't connect the dots to use it programmatically!